# FireStore - Real Time Data - Have problems to use onSnapshot

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

Using the following component I can connect to a Cloud FireStore collection and add new documents in to it.

Now, I'm trying to use the Real-Time-Data by using onSnapshot method, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';

const AddCard = ({ totalDoclNumbers }) => {
  const [newOriginalText, setNewOriginalText] = useState([]);
  const [newTranslatedText, setNewTranslatedText] = useState([]);
  const nextNumber = totalDoclNumbers + 1;

  const onAdd = async () => {
    await db.collection('FlashCards').add({
      originalText: newOriginalText,
      translatedText: newTranslatedText,
      customId: Number(nextNumber)
    });

  };

  return (
    <ul className='list'>
      <li className='list__item list__item--add' key={nextNumber}>
        <input
          type='text'
          defaultValue={nextNumber}
        />
        <div>
            <textarea
              onChange={(e) => setNewOriginalText(e.target.value)}
            />
          )}
        </div>
        <textarea
          onChange={(e) => setNewTranslatedText(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={onAdd}>
          Add
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};

export default AddCard;
```

This is what I tried:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';

const AddCard = ({ totalDoclNumbers }) => {
  const [newOriginalText, setNewOriginalText] = useState([]);
  const [newTranslatedText, setNewTranslatedText] = useState([]);
  const nextNumber = totalDoclNumbers + 1;

  const onAdd = async () => {
    await db
      .collection('FlashCards')
      .add({
        originalText: newOriginalText,
        translatedText: newTranslatedText,
        customId: Number(nextNumber),
      })
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let changeds = snapshot.docChanges();
        changeds.forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === 'added') {
            renderDocList();
          }
        });
      });
  };

  const renderDocList = () => {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li key={nextNumber}>
          <input
            type='text'
            defaultValue={nextNumber}
          />
          <div>
              <textarea
                onChange={(e) => setNewOriginalText(e.target.value)}
              />
            )}
          </div>
          <textarea
            onChange={(e) => setNewTranslatedText(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button onClick={onAdd}>
            Add
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      {renderDocList()}
    </>
  );
};

export default AddCard;
```

But once I click on the Add button, I get this error:

**Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.db.collection(...).add(...).onSnapshot is not a function**

Answer (score 0):

onSnapshot isn't working with add. The idea is that you want to subscribe to the collection so that whenever changes happen it will tell you.

so you need to do it this way

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';
  db.collection('FlashCards')
     .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let changeds = snapshot.docChanges();
        changeds.forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === 'added') {
            renderDocList();
          }
        });
  });
  const AddCard = ({ totalDoclNumbers }) => {
  const [newOriginalText, setNewOriginalText] = useState([]);
  const [newTranslatedText, setNewTranslatedText] = useState([]);
  const nextNumber = totalDoclNumbers + 1;

  const onAdd = async () => {
    await db
      .collection('FlashCards')
      .add({
        originalText: newOriginalText,
        translatedText: newTranslatedText,
        customId: Number(nextNumber),
      })
  };

  const renderDocList = () => {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li key={nextNumber}>
          <input
            type='text'
            defaultValue={nextNumber}
          />
          <div>
              <textarea
                onChange={(e) => setNewOriginalText(e.target.value)}
              />
            )}
          </div>
          <textarea
            onChange={(e) => setNewTranslatedText(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button onClick={onAdd}>
            Add
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      {renderDocList()}
    </>
  );
};

export default AddCard;
```

you can find other examples [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

Comment: Thanks, but your example throws this error: renderDocList(); is not defined

Comment: Move the subscription code after the definition of `renderDocList()` i was explaining the idea of subscription to a firebase collection. I didn't notice what you were calling inside it.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't update the UI. The new data get saved in the db but the UI doesn't update unless I refresh the page manually.

Comment: I can't see the whole code so i can't tell. the solution i have in mind right now is to move the subscription code inside function `onAdd` after you add the new record but it's not the best practice